# What do I need to do to accomplish "fire a job/alarm once at the beginning of next month to call an API" in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, scheduler, jobs, android-alarms

I'm new to Kotlin and Android, and as I try to research about job scheduler in Kotlin/Android, I'm overwhelmed with lots of ways, but all seems complicated in their own ways.

I'm developing a simple app that recording customer's feedback, that's mostly offline. But it has one feature that's online, and that is for sending report to some email addresses, via the help of an API, at the beginning of every month.

I need the simplest way to implement this, which:

- Can execute whether the app is active or destroyed -- so as a service?
- Does not have to be exact (inexact time is okay).
- I just need to fire once, because the app will set for next fire when the user interact with the app. Doesn't need to be repeated.
- Fire it at the beginning of next month.
- I can replace the existing job with the new job, if the previous job hasn't fired yet but the user already does another interaction with the app, as the report summarizes the whole month of activity. I read that alarm / job with the "same intent" can replace one another, although I'm not sure what that actually looks like in implementation.
- Because the data is in database, and I think I probably can't access the database when the app is inactive, I think I can put the data to be sent in the user shared preferences each time I set the job/alarm. I read somewhere that background service can read from shared preferences.
- Need to do network call.

So, if, for example, the needed data to sent is already on the shared preferences, what is the simplest / most basic way to accomplish this?

```
fun userDoInteractionWithApp (data: Data) {
    this.process (data)
    val report = this.generateThisMonthReport()
    this.scheduleNextReport(report, Date())
}

fun scheduleNextReport(report: String, curDate: Date) {
    this.saveToSharedPreferences ("report", report)
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.time = curDate
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10)
    val targetDate = c.time

    // and then?
}

fun sendReport() { // I want to fire this function, for example
    val report = this.loadFromSharedPreferences ("report") as String
    Network.sendReport(senderEmail, destinationEmail, "This is the report", report) // will run synchronously
}
```

Comment: No worries about the database. If your alarm fires and its code is running, that means your app is running (although not in the foreground with a UI visible) and you can access the database. You don't need to replace the alarm because when the alarm fires, the data you get from the database is the actual current data. Next to that you should probably indeed use WorkManager for this, just need to calculate how long to delay the job (how long until the begin of the next money)

Comment: @TimCastelijns oh alright, thanks for this confirmation!

Comment: Sidenote, there is no need to use `this.` unless e.g. you have to distinguish between variables with the same name

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes I understand that. I just want to give context that they’re custom methods within the class that you can just waive for the implementation when giving solution (just think that it’s already there).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to start app at exact time the best way to do that is with the

[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics.html)

You call it:

```
val uploadWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<YourWorker>()
        .build()
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(uploadWorkRequest)
```

You can set a delay chaining this:

.setInitialDelay(duration, TimeUnit)

Comment: Oh, interesting. Never heard about WorkManager before. I'm reading about it, and will let you know!